# How to display a continuous wc on stdout?

Tags: wc

Lets say you have this program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
while True: 
    print("True")
    time.sleep(1)
```

then you run it:

```
./clock.py | wc -l
```

This will never return anything because it waits for the output to finish before giving the word count.

I want something to run instead of wc -l that will display 1..2..3 like a clock almost.

Comment: @VojtechTrefny Im not sure how to do that in this case? tail is for looking at the end of a file but this is not a file, its generated output. tail -n +1 -f clock.py | awk '{printf "\r%lu", NR}' of course does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pv` to count and report lines output:

```
( while :; do echo True; sleep 1; done ) |
    pv --bytes --line-mode >/dev/null
```